# Running a script every 30 minutes with crontab using ROOT (Debian)

Tags: cron

When I manually type:

```
root@username:~# ./myscript.sh
```

The script executes, however I tried the following combinations to have crontab execute `myscript.sh` every 30 minutes (forever) and none seem to do anything:

```
# /etc/crontab: system-wide crontab
# Unlike any other crontab you don't have to run the `crontab'
# command to install the new version when you edit this file
# and files in /etc/cron.d. These files also have username fields,
# that none of the other crontabs do.

SHELL=/bin/sh
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin

# m h dom mon dow user  command
17 *    * * *   root    cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly
25 6    * * *   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.daily )
47 6    * * 7   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.weekly )
52 6    1 * *   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.monthly )
*/30 * * * * root sh /root/myscript.sh
*/30 * * * * root sh ./myscript.sh
*/30 * * * * root sh myscript.sh
*/30 * * * * root ./myscript.sh
```

---

Contents of myscript.sh:

```
KEYWORDS=("Word1" "Word2" "Word3" "Word4")
IFS=$'\n'
find . -size +1c -type f ! -exec grep -qwF "${KEYWORDS[*]}" {} \; -exec truncate -s 0 {} \;
```

Comment: Please post your script, also try adding `2> logfile` to your cron line so you can capture any errors.

Comment: `# cat /var/log/cron | grep myscript.sh`

Any errors?

Comment: `/var/log/cron` - in **CentOS**, in **Debian/Ubuntu** can be different logfile.

Comment: I bet it's a PATH issue.

Comment: setevoy: Yeah I enabled logging by editing /etc/rsyslog.conf -> uncommenting cron.*     /var/log/cron.log -> /etc/init.d/rsyslog restart (DEBIAN)

Comment: coteyr: It might be a path issue, but isn't the default root directory /root/ ? meaning */30 * * * * root sh /root/myscript.sh should be sufficient

Comment: @Guest in need of help OK, so now after 30 minutes will passed - take a look at log-file to see is it really run your script.

Comment: setevoy: localhost /usr/sbin/cron[2023]: (*system*) RELOAD (/etc/crontab)
localhost cron[2023]: Error: bad hour; while reading /etc/crontab
Jan 17 16:59:01 localhost /usr/sbin/cron[2023]: (*system*) ERROR (Syntax error, this crontab file will be ignored)
Jan 17 17:00:01 localhost /USR/SBIN/CRON[30233]: (root) CMD (root sh ./myscript.sh)
Jan 17 17:00:01 localhost /USR/SBIN/CRON[30234]: (root) CMD (root sh myscript.sh)
Jan 17 17:00:01 localhost /USR/SBIN/CRON[30235]: (root) CMD (root sh /root/myscript.sh)
Jan 17 17:00:01 localhost /USR/SBIN/CRON[30236]: (root) CMD (root ./myscript.sh)

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add information. It is hard to read and easy to miss in the comments.

Comment: Every one of those cron commands should actually work. If you don't see any files truncated, that's probably because you are not specifying the right directory to `find`. Does it work if `myscript.sh` is just `echo "Hello world"`?

Answer (score 2):

By the way - to run cron task every 30 minutes - try to use:

`00,30 * * * * [path_to_file]/myscript.sh`

Comment: So my format was incorrect?

Comment: `*/30` format must work too - but you can try other way if have problems.

Comment: I've tried a million different combinations nothing works... pastebin.com/N3GzHFXU

Answer (score 0):

To ensure your crontab works, you should always have full path to your code. To get the full directory to your code:

1. Go to the directory of your code.
2. Use the command `pwd`, which will print the directory you're in.
3. Use this directory with your script when appending to the crontab.

If you want your code to run every 30 minutes you can

```
*/30 * * * * /full/directory/to/your/code/mycode.sh
```

If you want your code to run on the hour ie XX:00 and 30 past the hour ie XX:30

```
 00,30 * * * * /full/directory/to/your/code/mycode.sh
```

If all of these are done, and you're still not getting the output you're expecting try looking at your `/var/log/syslog` files, you should be able to see what is going wrong.

Answer (score -1):

To run `cron` task every 30 minutes, `cron` expression will be like this:

```
*/30 * * * * /path-to-file/filename
```

Comment: This answer uses per user crontab syntax, which although root does have one, I recommend against using it as most people forget it is thare, and root can just use the system one anyway.